# Meaning of SoA in a review of an academic paper

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, acronyms

The reviewer of my paper said:

> It is not clear what is the main contribution regarding to SoA

And in another question he said:

> The SoA should be improved

What is the meaning of *SoA* here?

(For context, the paper is about 5G beamforming- I proposed a new method, I did not use the abbreviation of SoA in my paper)

Comment: SoA can mean different things in different contexts. What was the paper about?

Comment: Statement of Applicability? Skies of Arcadia? Knowing the field might help. This isn't general academic jargon but a more specific sort.

Comment: The paper is about 5G beamforming, I proposed a new method, I did not use the abbreviation of SoA in my paper,

Comment: This question is likely too specific to one discipline for ELU.

Comment: **State of the Art** seems out of context of the phrasing, but **service-oriented architecture** and **semiconductor optical amplifier** are discussed in many places relating to 5G.

Comment: Ask the reviewer.

Comment: The reviewer quote "It is not clear what is the main contribution regarding to SoA" suggests a non-native English speaker, so the usage of SoA could differ from common usage. Asking the reviewer is the only way to be sure.

Comment: What @barbecue said: *It is not clear what is the main contribution* is not “standard” English (we don’t invert embedded questions). Also, we say *regarding* — not *regarding to*. Lastly: I doubt the currently upvoted answer — “state of the art” — is correct here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reviewer is likely referring to **state of the art**, covered in or equivalent to the literature review for an academic work.

When researching the term, I found a reviewer note for another article that gave more of a clue from context:

> The **SoA** should be improved by adding more recent references, in the last 2-3 years some work on this topic have been published. ([MDPI Open Access Journals](https://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/23/5/2638/review_report))

The need to supply current research suggests that **SoA** appeals specifically to the timeliness or recency of the research. That points to the general sense of *state of the art* as what is current in your field and specialty regarding this project.

---

In certain STEM fields, perhaps in a European context, a literature review may also be referred to as a **state of the art** directly. Since a literature review often captures the state of research in a field, the connection between SoA and lit reviews makes sense. Here are some example showing the term in use:

> In scientific writing, the **state of the art** describes the current knowledge about the studied matter through the analysis of similar or related published work. (Cassia Trojahn dos Santos. "[How to write a good state of the art: should it be the first step of your thesis?](https://hal.science/hal-02161403)," 2019.)

> Most likely, you have been told that you are expected to write a "**state of the art**" passage or a literature review as the introductory chapter to your assignment, but what is, in fact, a "state of the art"? ("[What is a 'State of the art' /Litterature review](https://www.sdu.dk/en/bibliotek/studerende/opgaveskrivning/state-of-the-art)")

> Currently I'm facing a problem with a "**state of the art**" chapter, where I am supposed to describe the current state of the field I'm working in and I have no idea as to how to begin. ("[How to write a 'state of the art' chapter](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/16724/how-to-write-a-state-of-the-art-chapter)," Writing StackExchange).

One thing I note with most of these sources, and most usage I've seen, is that it comes from a European academic context. The first URL is French, the second Danish. Indeed, I can find French sources like [this one](https://expertmemoire.com/etat-de-lart/) that discuss the *l'état de l'art* section as one possibly like a literature review (*une revue de la littérature*).

As for the abbreviation, one might expect SA, SotA, or SoA. A few sources support the use of SoA in this sense:

> I am a researcher in the field of robotics for the rehabilitation of post-stroke patients, and in my work I have to read and write a lot of scientific papers (written by engineers and medicians from worldwide). **The State-of-the-art is often abbreviated with SoA** (with S and A capital letter and o lower case) or alternatively with SOTA (with all capital letters). ([Word Reference forum post](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/state-of-the-art-abbreviation-soa-vs-sota.2958157/))

> **SOA 2022 - State of the Art** ([ICU Management and Practice](https://healthmanagement.org/c/icu/event/soa-2022-state-of-the-art))

> **State of the Art (SoA)** is the current status of knowledge. ([Oslo University Hospital](https://www.ous-research.no/faq/?k=faq%2FChapters&aid=15736))

---

Finally, one caution for any reader who has seen this and thinks, "Great! I can use SoA and people will perfectly understand me." As I and several other readers initially indicated, SoA is not a clear abbreviation outside of a specific academic context. The reviewer could have glosses their own abbreviation and avoided much of this confusion.

Comment: It doesn't seem to fit the context of the phrasing: "The SoA (State of the Art) should be improved" is a peculiar thing to say. It is what it is.

Comment: @WeatherVane It fits fine to me if the author refers to the intro/literature review as the "state of the art." See the first usage I quote in full: "the state of the art describes the current knowledge about the studied matter through the analysis of similar or related published work." I've certainly seen "the literature review should be improved." See also the second quote: "a 'state of the art'."

Comment: Improving a literature review is quite different to improving the state of the art. You improve the **art itself**, not the state of it, which is what it is.

Comment: I agree the application of "state of the art" to refer to a literature review is clunky, but it's definitely an established usage. My suspicion is that European academics are translating their own terms for the literature review (e.g., "[l'état de l'art](https://expertmemoire-com.translate.goog/etat-de-lart/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp)").

Comment: I'm sorry the Q was closed for lack of context.

Comment: So, for those who are not initiated into this peculiar terminology, there are **two** distinct obstacles to understanding the intended meaning here: **(1)** the use of the abbreviation, instead of the full phrase, **(2)** referring to the review of the literature that represents the current state of the art as just *the state of the art*. The latter may be innocuous in some contexts, but is quite confusing here, as improving the review of the literature (a part of the submitted text) is something very different from improving the actual state of the art.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your response; the acronym refers to "State of the Art" more than the other cases. The reviewer should not use his abbreviation while conversing with people from other countries. I wrote in a variety of academic journals, and this is the first time I have seen this kind of abbreviation; I assumed it to be a universal term, but it appears that it isn't.

Comment: @WeatherVane it's awkward phrasing, but I take it to mean "you need to advance the state of the art in some way for the paper to be notable, and you need to make it clear to the reader exactly what that advance is" — which is run-of-the-mill stuff in academia.

Comment: @jsw29 The literature review isn't in scope here. Improving the actual state of the art is. If the paper "proposes a new method" it should be *better* than the best known methods — for some definition of "better", and maybe only under certain criteria — and the paper should state what the yardstick is, what the criteria are, and how the "competition" compares. That's what the editor note is about.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in previous comments and answers, the first idea coming to mind is "State of the Art".

As indicated by *Weather Vane* in his comment, SOA may refer to **Service-oriented architecture** in a software or telecommunication context.

> Service-oriented architecture (SOA) is a type of software design that
> makes software components reusable using service interfaces that use a
> common communication language over a network.

Given that the "o" of SoA is lowercase and that I don't see a direct link between signal processing and software architecture, the OP may confirm (or not?) that the acronym refers more to "State of the Art" than to "Service-oriented architecture".

Answer (score 0):

Dude, if you’re going to be “5G beamforming,” you’re going to need (or “improve”) a [Statement of Applicability (SoA)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22statement+of+applicability%22&biw=2184&bih=1150&tbm=bks&ei=wglbZJjzNN3bkPIPuIWU-Ag&ved=0ahUKEwiY3MaN4un-AhXdLUQIHbgCBY8Q4dUDCAg&oq=%22statement+of+applicability%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAxQAFgAYABoAHAAeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQA&sclient=gws-wiz-books).